# Password comparing in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-thread

So I have stored password as hash in shared preferences, when user puts password I need to make a hash of it and compare with stored one.

Should it be done in AsyncTask or Thread because calculation and comparison could freeze UI? And then do you know a clean way to recieve result (true, false) from asynctask or thread?

```
public void startGenerateCode(View view) {
    String pinCompare = pin; //pin is class variable obtained from editText
    pinCompare = tools.bin2hex(tools.getHash(pinCompare)); 

    if(pinCompare.compareTo(session.getDetails("Pin"))==0){
        generateCode();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void generateCode(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GeneratedCode.class);
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
    finish();
}
```

This is done in activity after button is pressed.

Comment: you can compare at onPost in asyncktask

Comment: @android_jain so asyncTask is good for this? And can I start new activity in onPost ? When activity is killed earlier then comparison is finished then onPost could start next activity either?

Comment: what you want explain  clearly confusing your question

Comment: you want to compare text stored in shared prefrence and comming from json

Comment: @android_jain No, comparing entered text transformed to hash with stored one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zolo,

I guess this process is triggered when someone presses a `Button`, such as login. I don't think you need any extra `Thread` to process the `Hash` calculus.

If you then have to connect to a server and send/receive data, then you should use it due to the asynchronous flow.

Response to comments on main post:
Yes, you can start an Activity in `onPostExecute`.

Code example:

```
public void startGenerateCode(View view) {

    // Disable button         
    Button button = (Butto) view;
    button.setEnabled(false);

    String pinCompare = pin; //pin is class variable obtained from editText
    pinCompare = tools.bin2hex(tools.getHash(pinCompare)); 

    if(pinCompare.compareTo(session.getDetails("Pin"))==0){
        generateCode();
    } else {
        // If the login fails, re-enable the button to try again
        button.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I did it by heart, so there may be mistakes.

Comment: Yes, process is triggered after Button press. But I did it like this and once I tried app, and pressed button it started the comparison and new activity has not started I pressed it again and when I was pressing back button I had that activity twice in ActivityStack... I was not able to do it again, but it has happend.

Comment: @Zolo That's another problem. If you want help on that, at least post your code.

Comment: @Zolo I think it's short. If the time it takes is less that 1 second, there is nothing to worry about. You can add some defensive programming, and disable the button after someone presses it so that there are no multiple activities launched. I edited my answer with the example.

Comment: @Zolo just added the example, check it out.